# How to add blur effect to a lazy column on Android versions lower than 12?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, android-jetpack-compose-tv

This works perfectly on Android versions 12+

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
           .testTag(TestTag)
           .fillMaxSize()
           .blur(blurredBackground)
```

I tried Cloudy library but it doesn't work so well. I'm making TV app

Comment: What do you mean by "add blur effect"? Can you please add some screenshots: One with your effect and one without your effect? That will help us help you.